# Translate List into List of Int

Tags: c#, linq

I have a json value as below

```
"BookShops": [
    {
        "Name": "Modern",
        "BookID": [
            "101"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "Windshore",
        "BookID": [
            "102"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "Winter",
        "BookID": [
            "105"
        ]
    },
]
```

Each of element of bookshops have only one bookID (even their type is int array) I want to move bookID into List Of Int just like the expect result

```
"GlobalBookID":[101,102,105]
```

that define in class as

```
List<int> GlobalBookIDs
```

Can I know to translate it in single line ?

Comment: The book IDs in your JSON are not numbers but strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to select the `BookID` integers.

```cs
var bookIds = bookshops.Select(b => b.BookID[0]);
```

However, why is the BookID an array of integers anyway?

Answer (score 1):

If *multiple* ids are possible (you have an array of for `BookID`) you can try `SelectMany`:

```
List<int> GlobalBookIDs = bookshops
  .SelectMany(shop => shop.BookID)
  .Select(id => Convert.ToInt32(id)) // you have ids being strings in your JSON
  // .Distinct() // uncomment if you want to get distinct BookIds
  .ToList();
```